# Automatic path adjustment when importing from plain JavaScript

Tags: typescript

In a TypeScript file I'm importing a primitive value from a JavaScript file located in some other folder (everything very simple, no need for a declaration file).

```js
// ./myCode.ts
import b = require("./pathToAfolderFarFarAway/IneedThis.js")
const allMyCode = 1+<number>b; // and that's it
```

When this TypeScript file is compiled, it is instructed by the `tsconfig.json` to be placed in `./somePath`:

```
{"compilerOptions":{"outDir":"./somePath"}}
```

The resulting `myCode.js` file compiles correctly and is placed in `./somePath`, but it cannot run from there because `require` is called with the same path as in the original `./myCode.ts`.  I would need either

1. the path in the `require` call in `./myCode.js` adjusted to account for this different location, or
2. `IneedThis.js` copied into `./somePath` with a relative location to `./myCode.js` compatible with the path in the `require` call.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are just missing the [`allowJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option in `tsconfig.json` to also include and compile `.js` files to the `outDir` folder. So the import references remain valid (your second bullet point).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "somePath",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```